# How to fix Verilog::VCD::Writer error: Can't locate object method addSignal?

Tags: perl, cpan

I suspect I made an import error in Perl.

There is a Perl module `Verilog::VCD::Writer` to write a VCD file. However, when I copy its SYNOPSIS code to have a try, it always raises the error:

> Can't locate object method "addSignal" via package
>   "Verilog::VCD::Writer" at tester.pl line 10.

The SYNOPSIS calls `addComment` and `addModule` before `addSignal` so there should be no problems in my installation.
`addSignal` is a function defined in `Verilog/VCD/Writer/Module.pm`, and the other two are defined in `Verilog/VCD/Writer.pm`. Even I add `Verilog::VCD::Writer::Module`, still the debugger go to package `Writer` to find the `addSignal` method.

If I call the `addSignal` function in this way:

```
$writer->Verilog::VCD::Writer::Module::addSignal("TX",7,0);
```

> Can't locate object method "signals_push" via package
>   "Verilog::VCD::Writer" at
>   /home/cqsun/lib/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/Verilog/VCD/Writer/Module.pm
>   line 41.

`Module.pm` defined signals_push in a hash, and clearly the debugger didn't find it.

I suspect there is something wrong, but I don't know where it is.

The webpage for this package is http://search.cpan.org/~jvs/Verilog-VCD-Writer-0.002/lib/Verilog/VCD/Writer.pm

Answer (score 1):

This is a documentation bug.

The code in the SYNOPSIS section of the POD has a few problems.  The error you see is from the line:

```
my $TX=$writer->addSignal("TX",7,0); #Add Signals to top
```

The code used the wrong object handle for the `addSignal` method.  `$writer` is an object of the `Verilog::VCD::Writer` module, and it does not have an `addSignal` method.  However, `addSignal` is a method of the [Verilog::VCD::Writer::Module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Verilog::VCD::Writer::Module) module.  The code needs to use `$top` instead of `$writer`.

The next line has the same problem:

```
my $RX=$writer->addSignal("RX",7,0);
```

Finally, the following line has a syntax error because it is missing the comment delimiter (`#`) after the semicolon:

```
my $dut=$top->addModule("DUT");  Create SubModule
```

Here is a fixed version of the code which runs without errors and generates a VCD output file:

```
use Verilog::VCD::Writer;
 
my $writer = Verilog::VCD::Writer->new(timescale=>'1 ns',vcdfile=>"test.vcd");
$writer->addComment("Author:Vijayvithal");
 
my $top = $writer->addModule("top"); # Create toplevel module
my $TX  = $top->addSignal("TX",7,0); #Add Signals to top
my $RX  = $top->addSignal("RX",7,0);
 
my $dut = $writer->addModule("DUT");  #Create SubModule
$dut->dupSignal($TX,"TX",7,0); #Duplicate signals from Top in submodule
$dut->dupSignal($RX,"RX",7,0);
 
$writer->writeHeaders(); # Output the VCD Header.
$writer->setTime(0); # Time 0
$writer->addValue($TX,0); # Record Transition
$writer->addValue($RX,0);
$writer->setTime(5); # Time 1ns
$writer->addValue($TX,1);
$writer->addValue($RX,0);
```

I uploaded a patch to the bug report you opened:
https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=123724

---

Also, the `Create SubModule` comment seems misleading.  Perhaps the author intended to use the [addSubModule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Verilog::VCD::Writer::Module#addSubModule(name,type)) method instead of the [addModule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Verilog::VCD::Writer#addModule(ModuleName)) method.

Comment: Thanks for your help toolic!

Comment: @MichaelSun: You're welcome.  The module author has fixed this in a new version (0.004).